# Two questions on trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Excuse me please. I cannot solve two tasks on trigonometry.

i) Prove the inequality
$$
\sin x (\sin x-2)+\cos^2 (x-1)>0.
$$

I've reduced it to
$$
(1-\sin x)^2-\sin^2 (x-1)>0,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
1-\sin x>|\sin (x-1)|.
$$

But I cannot prove the last inequality.

ii) Solve the equation
$$
4\tan\frac{x}{2}+2\tan\frac{x}{4}+\tan\frac{x}{8}=\tan\frac{x}{12}-\frac{8}{\tan x}.
$$

The answer says that it is equivalent to
$$
\cos\frac{5x}{12}=-1.
$$

But how to get it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The first inequality is false in general. The angle $x=1+\pi/2$ is in the second quadrant, so $\sin x>0$ and thus $(\sin x)(\sin x-2)<0$. But $\cos(x-1)=0$.

Comment: As stated, this inequality is false unless you put a bound on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant $~\sin x\cdot\sin(x-2)+\cos^2(x-1)>0$, which is indeed true, since it can be simplified to $(\cos1)^2>0$ using [angle addition formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) in conjunction with $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the inequality, as already said in the comments, it is false. If you plot the function $$f(x)=\sin x (\sin x-2)+\cos^2 (x-1)$$ you will identify that it shows $x$ intercepts at $x_1=1.10620$, $x_2=3.03539$, $x_3=7.38938$, $x_4=9.31858$, ... Between $x_1$ and $x_2$, $f(x) \lt 0$ as well as between $x_3$ and $x_4$ and so on.